# What is the TabLayoutPanel equivalent of TabPanel.getTabBar().setTabEnabled()

Tags: java, gwt

We have a webapp that we have been developing for a while now. We started development using GWT 2.0 and made heavy use of the `TabPanel`.

We recently upgraded to GWT 2.1, and I am now at the point of working through all of the deprecation warnings and replacing them with the 2.1 equivalents. However, it appears that the `TabLayoutPanel`, which is the replacement for the deprecated `TabPanel` is actually missing some functionality.

On many of our screens we make heavy use of tabs for data entry forms, and we often disable tabs during editing. We do this using:

```
TabPanel tabPanel = new TabPanel();
...
tabPanel.getTabBar().setTabEnabled(index, enabled);
```

Looking through the `TabLayoutPanel` documentation though, I cannot find the equivalent of this.

How do I dis-/en-able specific tabs in a `TabLayoutPanel`?

PS For bonus points, we also used to use `tabPanel.setAnimationEnabled(true)` because we liked the effect this had. This is obviously cosmetic, but we miss it too. Is there a `TabLayoutPanel` equivalent of that as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply add a `BeforeSelectionHandler` and `cancel` the selection event to disable the bar, then to re-enable it remove the handler. And for changing its appearance use TabBar's approach, you should change its source code.

By the way , From docs :
 * @deprecated Use {@link TabLayoutPanel} instead, `but understand that it is`
 *             `not a drop in replacement for this class`. It requires standards
 *             mode, and is most easily used under a {@link RootLayoutPanel} (as
 *             opposed to a {@link RootPanel}

Comment: In my opinion it's not deprecated at all, see this:

Comment: Jamshid, thanks for your reply. Did something get removed from your comment?

Comment: Jamshid, I am going to accept your answer, even if I probably won't go about implementing it. For now we are just going to stick with using the old TabPanel. It seems a bad move to deprecate something without providing something with similar functionality.

Comment: How do i remove the BeforeSelectionHandler event to enable the Tab?